# Insert into database from list in python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, list

Suppose I have  lists within a list. I want it to insert list item in database.

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['0.2', '2.3', '4'], ['5.4', '2', '3']]
```

here you will see that the main list has three sub-list. I want 1,0.2,5.4 in first-column of database, 2,2.3,2 in second-column of database and 3,4,3 in third column of database.
some portion of code is given:

```
FILE_NAME = "mmd.txt"
list=[]
with open(FILE_NAME, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n');
    for line in lines:
        list.append(line.split(','))

print list
for i in list:
    print i
    for j in i:
        print j
    print 'new line'
```

I can separate sub-list from list and I am also able to separate item from sub-list but how can I insert them into my database respectively? Please put your comment/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on the answer of `alecxe`, you should use `executemany`, and after the last `execute` command add a `commit` command like this. Assuming your database object name is `myDbName`:

> myDbName.commit()

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it with `executemany()`:

```
cursor.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        MYTABLE
        (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s)
""", mylist)
```

where, I am assuming `mylist` to be a list of lists with 3 items each:

```
[
    ['1', '2', '3'], 
    ['0.2', '2.3', '4'], 
    ['5.4', '2', '3']
]
```

And don't name your variable as `list` to avoid shadowing the built-in `list`.

Comment: @IrtizaKhanNiloy well, `cursor` is obviously `cur` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import MySQLdb

    my_list = [['1', '2', '3'], ['0.2', '2.3', '4'], ['5.4', '2', '3']]
    res_list = []

    for i,j,k in zip(my_list[0],my_list[1],my_list[2]):
        res_list.append(i+','+j+','+k)

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="", # your password
                          db="db_name")

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into tablename (column1,column2,column3) values(%s,%s,%s)",(res_list[0],res_list[1],res_list[2]))
```

Comment: Just expand the zip call `zip(my_list[0],my_list[1], ..., my_list10000])`

Comment: @Moberg that seems very clumsy to me. There must some efficient way to do this, I believe.